# laravel controller redirect just shows in console, doesn't actually redirect the page

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple controller that redirects upon completion, but when it completes it just shows me the URL and page in my console but the actual page doesn't redirect at all, just stays static

Controller.php

```
function saveImages(Request $request) {

    $data = $this->service->save(
        $request->type, 
        $request->image, 
    );

    return Redirect::to(route('images.show', $data))->send();
}
```

My console shows 302 found and then shows the correct url of 'site.com/images/show/45' and 45 is indeed the returned value.

Why isn't the actual page redirecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```php
return response()->redirectToRoute('images.show')->with($data);
```

Comment: This worked but it still loads the page within my web console , the origin page stays static. This is all being hit via axios call by the way

Comment: you will not be able to redirect pages using axios by using php redirects, you will get the redirect as you said in the console. the way to do it is by using axios redirects, that's a different area, i think your php code is fine then and that you need to do the redirect in axios side after you get the response or simply by using `window.location = '#'` where # is some url you said from the response, instead of return redirect, use return 'the-url';

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/axios-dosent-redirect

Answer (score 0):

I'm new on coding but i use redirect like this,

Did you try;

```
 return redirect(route('images.show', $data))->send();
```

Comment: I tried this as well, and I had previously but I just did again to be safe. It still just redirects in the console, unfortunately

Comment: did you try in a different browser?